# Scala SBT compile hangs (SBT 1.5.0, Scala 2.13.5, Java 11.0.10)

Tags: scala, sbt

In my project, the Scala/SBT build hangs infinitely in the `compile` step. To reproduce:

```
git clone https://github.com/gdiet/backup.git
cd backup
# fist the good case - compiles in less than 30s (when dependencies are fetched etc. etc.)
git checkout e8bdc8a1e878bd15129f08b20df51d54ebd86e4a
sbt compile
# now the problem - compile hangs infinitely
git checkout b273a531c19ad68600026429643e13c6d2761c16
sbt compile
```

(Sorry, I haven't been able to create a minimal demo example.) "clean" does not help. I can reproduce the problem on my Linux system with SBT, with IntelliJ IDEA, and in Docker. For Docker, run

```
# reproduce the problem in Docker - compile hangs infinitely
git checkout b273a531c19ad68600026429643e13c6d2761c16
./build-app.sh
```

Questions:

1. How can I find out whether this is a scalac problem or an SBT problem, so I can open a bug?
2. How can I get additional information on why the build hangs, so I can try to avoid the problem?

Comment: What changed significantly between those two commits?

Comment: it seems it has nothing to do with `sbt`, if you run `git diff e8bdc8a1e878bd15129f08b20df51d54ebd86e4a..b273a531c19ad68600026429643e13c6d2761c16` you will find many changes. Also, if you just revert to your old sbt (1.4.5) - it will hang as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I ...?* I just had to reduce the problem to its minimal scope. This is how I got there:

- Find a **minimal** change where compile works before and hangs afterwards.
- Isolate the problem code into a separate scala class/object/project.
- Check whether only `sbt compile` hangs or whether also `scalac` hangs (it does). In the latter case `scalac` is to blame.
- As for avoiding the problem: The detail investigation showed I used a `Vector` where the type system should require a `LazyList`. Change that to `LazyList` and everything works as expected. (See the minimal example below.)

My minimal example which causes scalac (scala 2.13.5) to hang now is:

```
object CompileHangs {
  def read1(): LazyList[Either[(Int, Int), String]] = ???
  def read2(): Option[LazyList[Either[(Int, Int), String]]] = ???

  def read(): LazyList[Either[(Int, Int), String]] =
    read1().flatMap {
      case Right(_) => LazyList()
      case Left(value) =>
        read2().getOrElse(
          // LazyList instead of Vector would be the correct thing here.
          // Use it and everything works as expected.
          Vector(Left(value))
        )
    }
}
```

Interesting side observation: If I switch `Either[(Int, Int), String]` to `Either[Int, String]`, compile works fine, even with `Vector`, although I would expect a typechecking error.

I will now create an bug report for `scalac`.